# python issue regarding "LearnPythonTheHardWay" book, ex18

Tags: python

Im having some issues to get exercise 18 'Names, variables, code, functions' to work. And to be very honest, i dont quite understand it either, like I didnt fully understand couple previous ones, but yeah.
Here is the code i've writed:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)


def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

def print_one(arg1):
    print "arg1: %r" % arg1


def print_none()
    print "I got nothing."

print_two("Zed", "Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed", "Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

line 15
def print_none()
SyntaxError    ^

Comment: If you didn't fully understand a couple of previous ones, "yeah" is not the correct response. The correct response is to understand them.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing a colon on the print_none() line.

Comment: No problem - sometimes it needs a fresh pair of eyes!